# Three models in one page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have three models (pipeline, stage, deal) with the following relations:

- a pipeline has many stages / a stage belongs to one pipeline
- a stage has many deals / a deal belongs to one stage

first i have to create a new pipeline (which is no problem), when i open the pipeline i have to do four things (in the pipelines show.html.erb)

- add new stages
- add new deals
- edit stages
- edit deals

so i am googeling for some days how to deal with that situation. it's no problem to add new stages to a pipeline, but i have no idea how to create new deals to a stage. i hope you understand the question someone can give me a hint how to add my deals.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `nested_attributes`. There is a nice [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) about this.

The basic idea behind `nested_attributes` is to do the following in your models:

```
class Pipeline
  has_many :stages

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stages
end

class Stage
  belongs_to :pipeline
  has_many :deals

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deals
end

class Deal
  belongs_to :stage
end
```

Then in your form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :stages do |b| %>
  <%= b.text_field ... %>

  <%= b.fields_for :deals do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field ... %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Don't forget to instantiate your classes in your controller as well:

```
class PipelinesController 
  def new
    @pipeline = Pipeline.new
    @stage    = @pipeline.stages.build
    @deal     = @stage.deals.build
  end
end
```

Comment: i think i get the idea from your post, but am i right that you use just one form here? i think i will need two forms (one for adding stages to the pipeline (which already works) and another one for adding deals to one of the stages. so i have no idea how to tell the deals controller that the newly created deal belongs to a specific stage. in the end i want a page like this: Pipelinename, then all the stages, under every stage i want to add/edit/delete deals. and beneath that i want to add/edit/delete stages.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use form objects. Check the section entitled "Extract Form Objects" to get the idea: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

You may also view this related railscast should you have access: http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects